# glsl strange behavior with frag shader and player movement

Tags: c++, glsl, sfml

im creating a 2d top down game in sfml where i would like the player to only be able to see things in their fov of 45 deg, currently my fragment shader looks like follows

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform vec2 pos;
uniform vec2 screenSize;
uniform float in_angle;

void main()
{
    vec2 fc = gl_FragCoord.xy/screenSize;
    vec2 ndcCoords = vec2(0.0);

    float fov = radians(45);
    ndcCoords = (pos + (screenSize/2))/screenSize;
    ndcCoords.y = abs(ndcCoords.y - 1.0);

    float angle = radians(-angle+90+45);

    float coT;
    float siT;

    vec2 adj = vec2(0.0);

    coT = cos(angle);
    siT = sin(angle);
    adj.x = coT * ndcCoords.x - siT * ndcCoords.y;
    adj.y = siT * ndcCoords.x + coT * ndcCoords.y;

    vec2 diff = normalize(ndcCoords - fc);

    float dist = acos(dot(diff, normalize(adj)));

    vec3 color = vec3(0.0f);

    if(dist < fov/2)
    {
        color = vec3(1.0);
    }

gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0) * texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
}
```

what this is doing is adjusting the playerPos vec2 and rotating it, so i can determine what fragcoords are within the players fov, however, when i move down without moving the mouse from directly above the player the fov shifts to the left / right without the player rotating at all, i've tried every solution i can think of but i can't seem to stop it, nor can i find a solution to this online. any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

a solution has arisen, instead of trying to rotate the object to get its vector2 normalised direction, a simpler method is to calculate the angle between a frag and the playerPosition followed by creating a difference by subtracting the player rotation in radians as shown below. this can then be adjusted for the coordinate space and compared to the players fov

```
void main()
{
    float fov = radians(45);
    float pi = radians(180);
    vec3 color = vec3(0.2);

    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/screenSize.xy;
    pos = (pos + (screenSize/2)) / screenSize;

    float angleToObj = atan2(st.y - pos.y, st.x - pos.x);
    float angleDiff = angleToObj - radians(-angle);

    if(angleDiff > pi)
        angleDiff -= 2.0f * pi;
    if(angleDiff < -pi)
        angleDiff += 2.0f * pi;
    if(abs(angleDiff) < fov/2)
        color = vec3(1.0f);   

gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0) * texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
}
```